# import svg file from local directory without using vue-svg-loader

Tags: vue.js, svg, vue-component

I just want to know if it's possible to import an svg file from local folder to a ".vue" file.

```
--home directory
  --> page.vue
  --> svg-directory
      --> svgFile.svg
```

I want to import svgFile.svg inside page.vue, doing something like:

```
import ....
```

or:

```
<img src="./svg-directory/svgFile.svg" />
```

or something else.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Vue uses webpack as asset bundler.

Webpack needs a loader for every single type of file it handles. Thankfully, you don't need to write each loader, as they come pre-configured for the most common types. However, `.svg` is not one of the pre-configured ones.

If you want to load `.svg`s in webpack, you have to teach webpack how to handle those files, which is exactly what `vue-svg-loader` or `svgo-loader` do.
Obviously, you don't have to use them. You can always write your own loader.

If you don't want to write any loader, you could take advantage of the `vue-loader`, which is already present in a vue application. Simply wrap your `<svg>` in a `<template>` tag and save it as `.vue`:

```
<template>
  <svg>...</svg>
</template>
```

Now you can import and use it as you would any other component.

This also comes with the advantage of having the `<svg>` inline, which means it can inherit `currentColor` so you could easily animate its color (which you can't when it's loaded as an `<img>`).

See it working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-lamarr-qjvkm?file=/src/App.vue

---

If you want to automate it and not have to wrap all the svgs in `<template>` tags and save them as `.vue`, here's an article explaining how you could do it:
https://codeburst.io/managing-svg-images-in-vue-js-applications-88a0570d8e88
using this loader:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
const requireTemplate = require.context( '.?vue-template', false, /\.svg$/ );
context.keys().forEach( fileName => {
  const name = 'Svg' + fileName.replace( /^\.\//, '' )
    .replace( /\.svg$/, '' ) );
  const withRender = requireTemplate( fileName );
  const component = withRender( {} );
  Vue.component( name, component );
});
```

Now you can import any `.svg` as you would import a `.vue` component and use it as a component.

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer! The `<template>` trick is nice.